# a href hover affect another a href

Tags: html, css

i have two  elements inside a container. i would like when hover the first the border becomes yellow and when hover the second the border of the first becomes yellow again.

here is my code :

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="href1"></a>
    <a href="#" class="href2"></a>
</div

.href1, .href2
{
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

.href1
{
    background:red;
    border:2px solid #000;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

.href1:hover
{
    border-color:yellow;
}

.href2
{
    background:blue;
}

.href2:hover .href1
{
    border-color:yellow;
}
```

i made an example http://jsfiddle.net/df5dwsq8/

i dont know why this is not working. if someone could help me i would appreciate it.

Comment: "*[I don't] know why this is not working*" - it's not working because there's no way, in CSS, to select a previous sibling (or parent) element of the current element; and your selector: `.href2:hover .href1` would select an element of class 'href1' within a hovered-element with the class of 'href2,' which doesn't match your HTML.

Comment: i understand now.. so the only way to achieve this is javascript?

Comment: Yes, JavaScript's required for this.

Comment: You need jQuery or javascript to do this

Comment: thanks a lot! and sorry for the duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
.href1, .href2
    {
        display:block;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
    }

.href1
    {
        background:red;
        border:2px solid #000;
        margin-bottom:30px;
    }

.href1:hover
    {
        border-color:yellow;
    }

.href2
    {
        background:blue;
        border:2px solid #000;
    }

.href2:hover 
    {
        border-color:yellow;
    }
```

Is this what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/jani11bolkvadze/df5dwsq8/1/ ??

Comment: no i want when hover the second (blue), then first' s border-color becomes yellow

Comment: use this script $(".href1").hover(function(){
    $(".href2").css("border", "2px solid yellow");
});